# XCode 5 - Center horizontaly several buttons width AutoLayout

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I'm a beginner in iOS development and I need some help please.

I have a view which contains 4 buttons. I would like to center vertically these button on the screen (but keep spaces between each button) using Auto Layout.

There is how my screen looks like :

```
 -------------------------
|     NAVIGATION BAR      |
|-------------------------|
|                         |
|  |------|     |------|  |
|  |      |     |      |  |
|  |      |     |      |  |
|  |------|     |------|  |
|                         |
|  |------|     |------|  |
|  |      |     |      |  |
|  |      |     |      |  |
|  |------|     |------|  |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
|         TAB BAR         |
 -------------------------
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy using auto layout, as auto layout is built for cases like these (even the string and struts model would solve this quite easily).

**1. All you have to do is create a wrapper `UIView` that contains the buttons.** The view should have clear - transparent background, so you will not see it at all.

```
 -------------------------
|     NAVIGATION BAR      |
|-------------------------|
|  ---------------------  |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| |                    || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
|  ---------------------  |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
|         TAB BAR         |
 -------------------------
```

**2. Then you have to set the constraints of that view to center horizontally and vertically.** This is the result below:

```
 -------------------------
|     NAVIGATION BAR      |
|-------------------------|
|                         |
|                         |
|  ---------------------  |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| |                    || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
|  ---------------------  |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
|         TAB BAR         |
 -------------------------
```

So when the view will be higher, you will get this result:

```
 -------------------------
|     NAVIGATION BAR      |
|-------------------------|
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|  ---------------------  |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| |                    || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||      |     |      || |
| ||------|     |------|| |
|  ---------------------  |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
|         TAB BAR         |
 -------------------------
```

You can do this both in Interface Builder or in code, as you wish. And I do suggest that you read some resources on how auto layout works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you using IB (interface builder, thats the graphical way in Xcode) or you adding constraints programmatically (using only lines of code in your ViewController)?

This is a quick guide for understanding autolayout:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L-CgBYCN6I

This is very good detailed tutorial for understanding and working with autolayout in IB (it is also up to date (2014.):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo

These are the apple documents which are great for doing constraints programmatically:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope this gets you a step closer to your solution.